# Leaflet WMS layer label disappears on zoom

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript, wms, sld

I am populating a **tileWMS** layer on my map (also created through **Leaflet**) through **Leaflet** from GeoServer which is working fine but the issue I am facing is with visibility of labels. On various **zoom levels** some labels are coming while some **disappears**, why is that happening?

Is this issue have something to do with the SLD or the Leaflet js library? 
Also, the issue exists only with a tiled WMS while the imageWMS works fine.
Following is my SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>polygon_with_label</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>A dark yellow polygon style</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>dark yellow polygon</Title>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#<ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>fillcolor</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>1dc159</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function></CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                <ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>fillopacity</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0.7</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#<ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>strokecolor</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>000000</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function></CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                                <ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>strokewidth</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Geometry>
                            <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Geometry>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>label</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>3</Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">
                                <ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>labelsize</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                                <Displacement>
                                    <DisplacementX>0</DisplacementX>
                                    <DisplacementY>5</DisplacementY>
                                </Displacement>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#<ogc:Function name="env">
                                    <ogc:Literal>labelcolor</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>000000</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function></CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Your SLD is invalid: `Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Function}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":PropertyName}' is expected.` (line 41) and `Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Font}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Fill}' is expected.` on line 52

Comment: Couldn't understand the issues you pointed in the SLD, can you please illaborate?